# How can I pass to my source code the package-lock.json file generated inside my container?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, package-lock.json

I am trying build a good workflow to work with docker and nodejs

I think that I have a good base, but I can not get the package-lock.json generated inside my container to my source code even though I have a defined volume

this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g nodemon
COPY ./src ./src

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["nodemon", "./src/index.js"]
```

and this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: nodemon ./src/index.js
    ports:
      - '8080:3000'
    volumes:
      - ./app/src:/app/src
      - /app/node_modules/
    links:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=dev
      - MYSQL_USER=dev
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=dev
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dev
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
```

In order to commit the package-lock.json to my version control tool, everytime I install a new package through `npm install` inside my container and a package-lock.json is generated/updated, I wanna move on to my source code the generated package-lock.json file

Comment: Does your `package.json` live inside the `./app` folder? This is where your docker context is at.. How does your repo look like in treeview?

Comment: Yes, my Dockerfile is in the `./app` folder

Comment: But where is your local `package.json` file? is it in `/project/app/package.json` or is it under `/project/src/package.json` or even within the root `/project/package.json`

Comment: my local `package.json` is in my `./app` folder, my  `Dockerfile` is in my `./app` folder and my  `docker-compose.yml` is in the root

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `/app` to volumes because `package-lock.json` will be generated in this directory, won't be?

Since this you could replace your volumes:

```
volumes:

    - ./app/src:/app/src

    - /app/node_modules/
```

on:

```
volumes:
    - ./app:/app
```

Also I would choose `/var/app` instead of `/app`.

Comment: It doesn't work this way: `Error: Cannot find module 'express'`